# WCF/Windows Service wrapper generates a non-thrown error

Tags: generics, service

Creating a windows service as a wrapper for a WCF library. As part of the process, you create a service host object and plug the wcf library into it. The problem is that it generates a "non-thrown" error... the code doesn't stop and the service starts but there's no reference to the library and so it's not listening for calls to the endpoint.

Image below shows the code and the error.

I'm a little stumped. Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to make. sure. the. endpoints. match. in all of the projects of the solution. In this solution's case, there are three config files to track and it's very easy to use a familiar or project name instead of the endpoint address. Fixing the endpoint addresses so that they match resolves this issue.